# Do lambdas assigned to void delegate discard non-void return type in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, void

I can call a non-void function from a lambda that's assigned to an Action (which expects a void return type):

```
static bool foo() { return true; }
...
// Action action = foo; // This gives a compile error though.
Action action = ()=>foo(); // This compiles
```

Initially I noticed this while looking at an example of `List.ForEach()`. I could execute a non-void function from the lambda and it compiled.

At first this seemed counter-intuitive, and made me think you can assign non-void functions to a `void` delegate (void acting like a sort of contravariant), but `Action action = foo;` didn't work.

So now I assume what's happening is that the lambda becomes void because that's the expected return type, so it discards the return type of the non-void function it calls. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example

```
Action action = ()=>foo();
```

is just like any other method:

```
public void MyTestMethod()
{
     // do something
     foo();
     // do some more
}
```

This is totally legal in C# (though some static analyzers would warn you that you don't use `foo()`'s return value).

THe second example:

```
action = foo;
```

does not work, because `foo` itself is a method with a return type and therefor can only be assigned to a variable of type `Func<bool>`, but not to `Action`. The lambda `() => foo()` on the other hand has no return type and is a valid `Action`.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. I guess it was just the mathematical-like notation `x=>f(x)` that makes it look counter-intuitive at first glance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this line of code :

```
Action action = ()=> foo(); // This compiles
```

You actually create another method that runs your function using *[closure](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)* :

```
void AnonymousMethod()
{
   foo();
}
```

To assign another method to a delegate that invokes method `foo` is not the same as assign `foo` method to delegate directly. And that's why line of code :

```
Action action = foo;
```

will not compile, because `Action` delegate has return type of void and method `foo` doesn't.